# How would I go about reading pixel data from a bitmap with BI_RLE8

Tags: c++, bitmap, compression

I got a working loader for 24 bit bmps, however it seems fairly common that the pictures I download to try is 8 bit and with compression BI_RLE8 (I dont know if there is a correlation between does 2 values? Are all 8 bit bmps compressed with BI_RLE8?), so I wanted to add functionality to it aswell, but it doesnt really come out rigth.

Rigth now I'm calculating the number of colors with:

```
numColours = 1 << bitmapInfoHeader.biBitCount;
```

then reading them in to colour tablet array:

```
rgbquad = new RGBQUAD[numColours];
in.read((char*)rgbquad, sizeof(RGBQUAD)*numColours);
```

Reading the pixels

```
LONG imageSize = (LONG)((float)bitmapInfoHeader.biHeight * (float)bitmapInfoHeader.biWidth * ((float)bitmapInfoHeader.biBitCount/8));
BYTE *bitmapImage=new BYTE[imageSize];
in.seekg(bitmapFileHeader.bfOffBits, std::ios::beg);
in.read((char*)bitmapImage, imageSize);
```

then when I extract the data like this

```
for(int j=0, k = 0; j< bitmapInfoHeader.biHeight; j++){
    for(int i=0; i < bitmapInfoHeader.biWidth; i++){
        index = ( bitmapInfoHeader.biWidth * j) + i;
        pixelMap[index].setR(rgbquad[bitmapImage[k]].rgbRed);
        pixelMap[index].setG(rgbquad[bitmapImage[k]].rgbGreen);
        pixelMap[index].setB(rgbquad[bitmapImage[k]].rgbBlue);
        pixelMap[index].setA(255);
        ++k;
    }
}
```

Some pictures for comparision:

Original image:

[image: Original image]

After Loading an rewritting:
[image: After Loading an rewritting]

I seems that the pixels are being read wrong, So could anyone show me how you are suppose to load them, or point me in the direction of a guide that does ?

Comment: Your code will never work for any 24 bit bitmap at all. The reason is because your for loops do not take into account padding. Next, if it is RLE encoded, you must decode the pixels for and then run the for-loop that is supposed to take into account padding.

Comment: No, this is most certainly **not** a common image format, RLE compression was used in the stone-age.  And it is certainly isn't the format of the image you posted, it is a JPEG image.  Which requires a decoder, a very untrivial one that you don't write yourself.

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames I got other code I that take padding in to account (mainly that my functions throws if the width isnt rigth) I may implement it later, just wanted to do the other parts first so i got that rigth.
Hans Passant. The pictures i uploaded are print screens of the originals ( Not sure why it wouldnt upload the originals, think they where to big or something)

Comment: @HansPassant So in other words, Im just that unlucky that i manage to pick 3 8 bit pictures with RLE?

Comment: You just look thoroughly confused about image formats.  You picked JPEG images, that doesn't require any luck.  Reading such a file as though it is a BMP file just generates random junk values.  Look at the file header with a hex viewer, JPEG files start with "JFIF" at offset 6.  If that's not what you see then you should post a better link to the image file you are actually using.

Comment: @HansPassant Read the comments again plz. The first one, sorry if I confused you